# C++ Bool Returning Hexadecimal Int?

Tags: c++

I'm looking through some code, and I see a bool function which defines an int with a hex value and returns it. Here's how it looks:

```
bool AttachProcess()
{
    int a = 0x40;
    ...
    return a;
}
```

Doesn't a bool only return true of false? Or 0 or 1? This function doesn't give an error or warning, so I must be missing something. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ zero is considered false, and everything non-zero is true. In your case there's an implicit conversion from the integer to a boolean value.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`true` and `false` are non-zero and zero.  So :-

```
return a;
```

is

```
return a != 0;
```